# Error when using view model with two models in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Following Example 2 here: [Multiple Models in Single View in MVC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/)

I have created a view model:

```
public class FOFDTO : BaseViewModel
{
    public FOFFacilityDTO Facility { get; set; }
    public FOFRegulatoryDTO FOFRegulatory { get; set; }
}
```

I don't need them IEnumerable since each will only have one record/row.

I then have in my view:

```
<label asp-for='@Model.Facility.FacilityName' class="form-label"></label>
<input asp-for='@Model.Facility.FacilityName' class="form-control" />
...
```

I have confirmed that all the rest of the references in the view follow the same convention: @Model..

And, there are no errors showing on the page either in the error section at the bottom or with red squiggles.

Yet when I try to compile, I get this message:

```
 The type arguments for method 'IModelExpressionProvider.CreateModelExpression<TModel, TValue>
 (ViewDataDictionary<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>)'
 cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

The error appears twice both times exactly the same wording and referencing line 1 of the .cshtml file.

```
@model MyPlanTools5.Models.FOF.FOFDTO
```

If it makes any difference, we are doing it this way because there is a lot of data to transfer and we only want to transfer for the particular active section using ajax when the user calls for that section.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks,
John

Comment: Can you share your action for the view?

Comment: I finally fixed this but don't remember exactly how. I think it may have been a formatting issue. Anyway,  if/when I do, I'll post the answer. Thanks,